# Notice: Array to string conversion in .... on line 57

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
 $user=$_SESSION['user'];
            $data=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select content.judul_content, content.kode_kategori, userapp.nama_lengkap from kategori kategori, content content, userapp userapp where kategori.kode_kategori=content.kode_kategori and kategori.kode_kategori='$user' and content.kode_content=userapp.kode_user"));

            $nama_siswa=$data['nama_siswa'];
            $nis=$data['nis'];
            $nama_kelas=$data['nama_kelas'];

?>
```

i have wrong message

Notice: Array to string conversion in this my line 57 .. $data=mysql_fetch_array......

Comment: There is *only one thing* in that line which could be converted to anything, and that is the value of `$user` that you are injecting in the query.

Comment: check if $user is an array or string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <?php
 $user=$_SESSION['user'];
 $query=mysql_query("select nama_siswa,nama_kelas,nis,content.judul_content, content.kode_kategori, userapp.nama_lengkap from kategori kategori, content content, userapp userapp where kategori.kode_kategori=content.kode_kategori and kategori.kode_kategori='$user' and content.kode_content=userapp.kode_user") or die(mysql_error());
       while($data=mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $nama_siswa=$data['nama_siswa'];
        $nis=$data['nis'];
        $nama_kelas=$data['nama_kelas'];
       echo $nama_siswa ." ".$nis . " " .$$nama_kelas ."<br />";

       }

?>
```

Edit:

try replace this

```
  $_SESSION['user'] = array('username' => $result[0]['username'],'nama_lengkap' => $result[0]['nama_lengkap']);
```

by

```
  $_SESSION['user'] =  $result[0]['username'];
  $_SESSION['nama_lengkap'] =  $result[0]['nama_lengkap'];
```

Comment: same result this my login<?php
 include 'function.php';
 if($_POST){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  
  $result = get_user("where username = '$username' and password = '$password'");
  if($result != NULL){
   session_start();   
   $_SESSION['user'] = array('username' => $result[0]['username'],'nama_lengkap' =>  $result[0]['nama_lengkap']);
   $_SESSION['kcfinder_mati'] = false;
   header("location:index.php");
  }else{
   header("location:login.php?message=0");
  }
 }
?>

Comment: yes , `$_SESSION['user'] ` is an array , is not a single variable to use it inside your query.

Comment: try edited answer and use every variable alone `$_SESSION['user']` and ` $_SESSION['nama_lengkap']`

Comment: i change to this  $user=$_SESSION['user']['username']; but no data result display

Comment: no let it like it is , `$user=$_SESSION['user'];`

Comment: yes that work no message Notice: Array to string conversion in appear but i worng to select my table so that nothing result maybe i must to change my query

Comment: is it possible to display table content based on username login ?

Comment: glad it worked for you . yes you can . good luck